# how to import oracle dump file to oracle db?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have customer oracle dump file, I used the following command to import this file to oracle db:

```
imp  user1/tartan@app92g fromuser=SYS touser=user1_1 file=PRD_10_06_11.dmp log=app_log1.log
```

But it occurs the following error:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
IMP-00010: not a valid export file, header failed verification
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

So I am thinking it is not exported by oracle common imp/exp process, it should be exported by pump, Is anybody have idea what command I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`impdp`](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/OracleDataPump10g.php).

The best thing to do is to ask your customer how he produced this dump though.